# Swift protocol inheritance and dynamic object confusion

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Trying with here is my setup:

```
protocol CommonFeatureProtocol { }
extension CommonFeatureProtocol { }


 protocol SpecificFeature1Protocol : CommonFeatureProtocol { 
     func specificFeature1Method()
  }


 protocol SpecificFeature2Protocol : CommonFeatureProtocol { 
      func specificFeature2Method()
 }

struct specificFeature1 : SpecificFeature1Protocol { }
struct specificFeature2 : SpecificFeature2Protocol { }
```

Now in one of my other class (`UtilFeature`), Will it be possible to use feature object and specific feature methods like -

```
UtilFeature.feature.specificFeature1Method()
UtilFeature.feature.specificFeature2Method()
```

Something like (in `UtilFeature`) -

```
var feature : CommonFeatureProtocol {
    return specificFeature1() //or specificFeature2()
}
```

Comment: What is not working. What did you expect?

Comment: Note that keywords such as `protocol` & `struct` need to be lowercase (your code won't compile). Also type names should be `UpperCamelCase`, e.g `SpecificFeature1Protocol`. Otherwise `specificFeature1()` looks like a function call.

Comment: @Mundi: UtilFeature.feature.specificFeature1Method() would not work as commonFeatureProtocol does not have  specificFeature1Method()

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve seems not possible as the feature is of type `CommonFeatureProtocol` and it does not include the method. So it's not possible to access with object(dot) method.

**POSSIBLE:**

```
var feature : SpecificFeature1Protocol {
    return specificFeature1()
}

feature.specificFeature1Method()
```

**Or(Not preferred way of doing)**

```
var newFeature : CommonFeatureProtocol {
    return specificFeature1()
}

(newFeature as SpecificFeature1Protocol).specificFeature1Method()
```

Got the point what you want to do is,

You need to make a composition of two protocols.

**Syntax**: `var composition: [Protocol1 & Protocol2]`

Also, you can use `typealias` to make it more readable.

So, In your case:

```
typealias SpecificFeatureProtocol = SpecificFeature1Protocol & SpecificFeature2Protocol

var feature: SpecificFeatureProtocol? {
    return nil
}
```

Now, you can use the methods like below:

```
feature?.specificFeature1Method()
feature?.specificFeature2Method()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have understood your question correctly

Yes it is possible, consider the following simple example.

```
protocol P0 {}
protocol P1 : P0 {}
protocol P2 : P0 {}

class C1 : P1 {}

let p : P0 = C1() //Expects p to be of the type P0
```